# Returning authenticated user's data in REST

Tags: rest, express, oauth-2.0, firebase, sails.js

I'm new using REST api and I understood that OAuth 2.0 is a greate way to handle authentication security but: Is there a standard/best-practice to return only the authenticated user's datas ?

For example,
User 1 authenticated try to access (GET) the url .#/myBooks that doesn't give the same result as if the User 2 is logged in.

Is it possible using Firebase ? 
What is the server guideline using Sails or Express on Nodejs ?

Any good tutorial (because I could not find any) would also be appreciate! ;-)

Many thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can secure your data in [Firebase using its security rules](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/). With the correct `.read` rules in place, a user can only see their own data.

Did you read this quick start? https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/quickstart.html

There is also a nice tool to simplify creating advanced security rules. I don't think you'll need it for the use-case you described, but it may come in handy later: https://github.com/firebase/blaze_compiler

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks for your reply. I read more in detail the doc and I found my answer

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://passportjs.org/

Comment: Thanks! This will be perfect lib to use whith sails/nodejs.